# How to charge a capacitor using repeatable damped sinusoid current signals?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, rectifier, charging

I am trying to charge a capacitor using repeatable damped sinusoid current signals from a piezoelectric bender - Result of the free vibration of the piezo beam(Current source plus piezoelectric capacitance in parallel). The current from the piezo bender is rectified and used to charge a capacitor. I have simulated it Matlab/Simulink but it yields a weird behaviour when the input is a damped sinusoid current signals. The voltage across the capacitor never reaches the open circuit voltage but grows indefinitely.

[image]

This is the expected behaviour (From a sinusoidal no-damped current input):
Graph1: Voltage Across Cp1(Piezo Bender)
Graph2: Voltage Across Capacitor that is being charged.
[image]

However, this is what I get (The voltage across the capacitor never reaches the open circuit voltage but grows indefinitely):
Graph1: Voltage Across Cp1(Piezo Bender)
Graph2: Voltage Across Capacitor that is being charged.
[image]

Would you have any suggestion on how to fix this problem?
Thank you very much for your help in advance.
Best wishes,
Lucas

Answer (score 1):

> *I have simulated it Matlab/Simulink but it yields a weird behaviour
> when the input is a damped sinusoid \$\color{red}{\text{current}}\$ signal*

You are using a \$\color{red}{\text{current}}\$ signal and that will inevitably keep putting charge into the storage capacitor. Just think about what a capacitor does when you apply a current source to it: -

$$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}\longrightarrow V = \dfrac{1}{C}\int i.dt$$

Voltage rises to infinity.

Comment: Hi @Andy. Thank you for your response. They same does not happen when a no-damped sinusoidal input is used instead, which reaches a constant steady state. According to your equation, the same should happen for both cases though. So my question is why it works for the non-damped and does not work for the damped case. My knowledge in electronics is very limited, so I'm sorry if I missed if you meant something else.

Comment: I think you should embed your actual simulated circuit into your question so there can be zero ambiguity or doubt. You should also check what the voltage magnitudes of the damped and undamped waveforms produce when feeding a capacitor via a single diode rectifier. In other words, remove doubt and double check things by comparison.

Comment: Hi @Andy. Thank you for getting back to me. I will keep working on it and update the post if I find out what is happening here. Thank you.